# Powershell script while executing mysqldump script

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysqldump, windows, powershell

I'm having an error 1045: Access denied for user 'mysqlsuperuser'@'test.internal.cloudapp.net' (using password: YES) when trying to connect

Here is the mysqldump command on my ps1 file.

```
$command = [string]::format("`"{0}`" -u {1} -p{2} -h {3} --default-character-set=utf8mb4 --quick --master-data=2 --single-transaction --routines --databases test1 --add-drop-database --result-file=`"{5}`" ",
        $mysqlDumpLocation,
        $databaseUsername,
        $databasePassword,
        $databaseIp,
        $database.DatabaseName,
        $saveFilePath);
```

But when I try to remove the {2} which is the DB password, then execute the ps1 file. When it prompt me for the password, it goes through.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that there's one or more characters in the password that are "confusing" the shell.

There are standard techniques for supplying passwords to mysql utilities that *avoids* having to have them coded into scripts or visible to any process list run on the machine.
See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205180/how-to-pass-password-to-mysql-command-line).